# Occasional crash on Android when loading images?

Tags: android, imageview, forceclose

I have a mechanism that I'm still working on, I'm trying to digest the code and I've gotten what I have from various sources. Basically there is an ImageView where you get to set your profile picture, you can either take a picture with the camera or choose a picture from the gallery. I have the following:

```
public void selectPhoto(View view) {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, CHOOSE_PHOTO);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case CHOOSE_PHOTO:
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = null;
            try {
                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selImageView)).setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've narrowed down the source of my mistake the above code. The crash occurs when the user prompts to select a photo from the Gallery, but then presses back instead of choosing a photo and tries returning to the app. Any ideas why?

Comment: you should try checking logcat, then posting the log here so people can help you debug more effectively! =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onActivityResult you are not checking the resultCode to see if the result was canceled or not. You are then proceeding like an image was passed. Most likely, because resultCode will indicate cancelation your selectedImage variable is null and openInputStream doesn't like opening the stream.

Furthermore, after the exception is thrown you are then passing a null imageStream to the decodeStream method.

Try something like:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case CHOOSE_PHOTO:
        if (resultCode = Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = null;
            try {
                imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
               ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selImageView)).setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
           // handle cancelation
        }
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I used a similar solution this works. I do have a follow up; if I use the CHOOSE_PHOTO option and select a photo, this works. If I CHOOSE_PHOTO a second time and select another photo, the app crashes; any idea why?